# Counting dates within interval in R

Tags: r, date

Given a set of dates as follows plus 30-day intervals ending at each date, I'd like to count the number of dates that fall within the interval, e.g.,

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
               dates = as.Date(c('2017-01-15', '2017-01-17', '2017-02-01', 
                               '2017-02-12', '2017-03-30', '2017-04-01')))

df <- df %>% mutate(interval = interval(dates - 30, dates))
```

Using

```
sum(x$dates %within% x$interval[5])
```

properly returns 1, since only one date falls within the 5th interval, but I'd like to do this in a vectorized fashion for all intervals. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: One possibility that seems to work okay is `f <- function(interval, date_vec) {
  
  sum(date_vec %within% interval)
  
}

df$dates_in_interval <- sapply(df$interval, f, df$dates)`

Comment: Or `colSums(outer(df$dates, df$interval, \`%within%\`))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `purrr::map_int`, we can go through the column on intervals and get the number of dates within each one. Note that this is not "vectorised" but I think does what you want.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  dates = as.Date(c(
    "2017-01-15", "2017-01-17", "2017-02-01",
    "2017-02-12", "2017-03-30", "2017-04-01"
  ))
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    interval = interval(dates - 30, dates),
    dates_in_intv = map_int(interval, function(x) sum(.$dates %within% x))
    )
#>   id      dates                       interval dates_in_intv
#> 1  1 2017-01-15 2016-12-16 UTC--2017-01-15 UTC             1
#> 2  2 2017-01-17 2016-12-18 UTC--2017-01-17 UTC             2
#> 3  3 2017-02-01 2017-01-02 UTC--2017-02-01 UTC             3
#> 4  4 2017-02-12 2017-01-13 UTC--2017-02-12 UTC             4
#> 5  5 2017-03-30 2017-02-28 UTC--2017-03-30 UTC             1
#> 6  6 2017-04-01 2017-03-02 UTC--2017-04-01 UTC             2
```

Created on 2018-04-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).